# Remove ./ from folder name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I am running the following code :

```
foldarz = [ f.path for f in os.scandir('.') if f.is_dir() ]
print(foldarz)
```

This prints the folder name correctly, but with a prepended ".\". I don't want the ".\".

I know I can split the string etc, but I assume there's a better way without having to call another function.

Comment: I guess you can do: `os.path.basename(f)` instead of `f.path`.

Comment: `f.path[2:]` or `f.path[3:]`? Or `f.name`? ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.name

Comment: `f.name` works for me, maybe I misread the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

```
foldarz = [os.path.basename(f) for f in os.scandir('.') if f.is_dir()]
```

Comment: Looks like you're calling another function — something the OP wishes to avoid.

Comment: That seems to be the question (although that's not clear based on a comment made by OP).

Comment: I just noticed. How I read the question is like OP doesn't want to use string functions like `split`.

Comment: For the record, I personally think your answer's fine (because I don't know why calling a function is an issue).

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.normpath` should help you remove the leading '.\' and give you the normalized path preferred by your operating system (think '/' instead of '\' depending upon user's OS)

```
foldarz = [os.path.normpath(f) for f in os.scandir('.') if f.is_dir()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use other functions, you can also use [`os.DirEntry.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry):

```
foldarz = [ f.name for f in os.scandir('.') if f.is_dir() ]
print(foldarz)
```